# Shortest/cleanest way to turn an integer of unknown size into its unsigned form?

Tags: c++, integer-arithmetic

I'm writing some code to format a hex number, and currently it accepts an unsigned 64-bit value.  This was all fine and dandy until I realized that it formats a 32-bit signed integer with too much sign extension, that is, "-1" becomes "ffffffffffffffff".

I could solve this by using numeric_limits<T>::digits:

```
template<class Int>
void Format(Int v) {
  switch(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits) {
    case 7:
    case 8:
      CallFormatRoutine(0xFF & v);
    break;
    case 15:
    case 16:
      CallFormatRoutine(0xFFFF & v);
    break;
    case 31:
    case 32:
      CallFormatRoutine(0xFFFFFFFF & v);
    break;
    case 63:
    case 64:
      CallFormatRoutine(v);
    break;
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if there was some better (shorter) way.  Specifically, a better way that works with C++03 and C++11.  Ideally there would be some routine that would return the unsigned version of any integer you give it, but I haven't been able to find that in the standard.  If I could use C++11, I could write this, albeit perhaps with a cast to avoid a warning about signed/unsigned conversion:

```
template<class Int>
void Format(Int v) {
  std::make_unsigned<Int>::type unsigned_v = v;
  CallFormatRoutine(unsigned_v);
}
```

Is there anything nice and short to do this, that also works with C++03?

Comment: Interestingly, if you add an unsigned zero integer to a signed integer, that makes it unsigned, so that works well, except that if you add an unsigned char to a signed char, they are both promoted (sign-extended) to int first, so this trick only works for "int".

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_unsigned` is the nicest and shortest way to accomplish what you want, but you have some errors in your example. It should look something like this:

```
template<class Int>
Format(Int v) {
  auto unsigned_v = static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<Int>::type>(v);
  CallFormatRoutine(unsigned_v);
}
```

And with a C++14 compiler, the relevant line can be shortened to

```
auto unsigned_v = static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<Int>>(v);
```

For C++03 compilers, there's [`boost::make_unsigned`](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/make_unsigned.html), or you could implement it yourself, but that's a little tedious because you need to handle all the built-in types.

```
template<typename T>
struct make_unsigned
{ typedef T type; };

template<>
struct make_unsigned<char>
{ typedef unsigned char type; };

template<>
struct make_unsigned<signed char>
{ typedef unsigned char type; };
```

Similarly, add specializations for `short`, `int` and the remaining integral types.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I ended up going with just using sizeof instead of std::numeric_limits, and using static_cast rather than 0xFFFFFFFF:

```
template<class Int>
void Format(Int v) {
  static_assert(sizeof(v) == 1 || sizeof(v) == 2 || sizeof(v) == 4 || sizeof(v) == 8,
                "Unknown integer type");
  CallFormatRoutine( sizeof(v) == 1 ? static_cast<uint8>(v)
                   : sizeof(v) == 2 ? static_cast<uint16>(v)
                   : sizeof(v) == 4 ? static_cast<uint32>(v)
                   : static_cast<uint64>(v);
}
```

(I tried to post this a comment to my question but couldn't get multiline code to format correctly.)

Comment: Did you actually try to use this function? The way you have it written, that `static_assert` will fail for any type that is not 8 bytes in size.

Comment: Thanks Praetorian.  Actually I was able to tighten it up a little further using ?: to avoid multiline if.

Comment: Yeah that looks better. I'd also throw in a `static_assert(std::is_integral<Int>::value, "...")` to ensure you're only passed integral types. And I'm not sure what those typedefs you're using are, but I'd recommend using `uintXX_t` types defined in `stdint.h`.

Comment: Yeah I would, but unfortunately is_integral is a C++11 feature.  And uint64_t is as well, sigh.  Mine are typedef'd by my environment but nearly every C++ shop I've worked in has found a way to define their own.  Hopefully the day will soon come where I can just rely on uint64_t and uint32_t being there.

Comment: Side note: regarding is_integral, I actually want to allow enum types, but disallow floating-point types.  I'm not sure what happens to enums with is_integral and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral doesn't mention enum.  (Though there does exist std::is_enum)